# Selenium chrome driver version not being updated in asp.net core selenium test

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently running into issues with selenium tests failing locally and on the devops azure pipe lines part of selenium testing.

The error is basically a version mismatch between the browser and driver being used.

I have tried installing the up to date driver for Chrome but I still keep getting the same error. On the pipeline I get that both drivers are the wrong version for the browser being used? Before this Selenium Tests would run without issues.

This is my csproj file for the test project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Vsxmd" Version="1.4.5">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.test.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"></None>
    <None Update="Drivers\chromedriver.exe">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Drivers\msedgedriver.exe">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Below is the folder where I store the drivers:

[image]

The error that the browser being used has a different version than the driver.

[image]

The driver folder that gets output to Tests.Selenium\bin\Debug\net6.0
will have the older version on it instead of the new
[image] updated version.

How can I know which version is truly required to cover what browser is being run on the piple line and locally?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
I looked at the Drivers folder in the bin folder and it seems like the updated drivers do not appear in the bin folder driver folder. Instead the older version drivers appear. I went into task manager closed all instances of the drivers and then deleted the entire bin and obj folders. Updated the driver folder again and it worked.

For some reason the updated driver folder does not get output to bin.